# Why get method in ConcurrentHashMap is blocking?

Tags: java, locking, concurrenthashmap

I have a question on ConcurrentHashMap in java. It internally calls readValueUnderLock. Why locking is required in case of get operation. And in which case this condition will be true
    (Entry.value==null)
which cause readValueUnderLock to be called)

Answer (score 4):

From the source code java doc comment of  `readValueUnderLock`

```
  /**
     * Reads value field of an entry under lock. Called if value
     * field ever appears to be null. This is possible only if a
     * compiler happens to reorder a HashEntry initialization with
     * its table assignment, which is legal under memory model
     * but is not known to ever occur.
     */
```

From this [link](http://old.nabble.com/Numa-and-ReentrantLock-td29549241.html)

> Not quite. You are right that it should never be called.
>   However, the JLS/JMM can be read as not absolutely
>   forbidding it from being called because of weaknesses
>   in required ordering relationships among finals
>   vs volatiles set in constructors (key is final, value is
>   volatile), wrt the reads by threads using the
>   entry objects. (In JMM-ese, ordering constraints for
>   finals fall outside of the synchronizes-with relation.)
>   That's the issue the doc comment (pasted below) refers to.
>   No one has ever thought of any practical loophole that a
>   processor/compiler might find to produce a null value read,
>   and it may be provable that none exist (and perhaps someday
>   a JLS/JMM revision will fill in gaps to clarify this),
>   but Bill Pugh once suggested we put this in anyway just
>   for the sake of being conservatively pedantically correct.
>   In retrospect, I'm not so sure this was a good idea, since
>   it leads people to come up with exotic theories.

Comment: But not sure how the HashEntry initialization can be reordered with its table assignment,I want to understand in which condition key won't be null and value could be null, From the java doc it also seems is not known to ever occur, then why they included this method for locking (As HashEntry is effectively immuatable all fields are final except value which is volatile)

Comment: @tarunk From javadoc it seems that it is written for a special case.

Comment: Yes, Any Idea of that special case, how it can happen, as jsr 133 gives the guarantee of ordering on final/volatile variables.

Comment: Thanks Amit,but still I have some doubt, as there is some initialization guarantee in constructor(by making sure this is not esacped during construction),that no other thread can read the object while its being constructed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to read a value from a hash map the code must find the value first. If another thread adds a value while the first thread is finding the value it could derail the search. Essentially the hash map could do something like:

```
calculate hash
go to location hash in the array
look to see if there's a list
iterate through the list until value is found
```

If this list is say an array list and the other thread needs to resize it, this would be a big problem for the thread iterating through it.